# how the ternary operator is working in this case?

Tags: operator-keyword

I am assigning **a** and **b** by ternary operator .But ,the output was not I expected

```
int a ,b;
a ,b = 1 ? 4 , 3 : 6 , 5;
printf("a : %d , b : %d",a,b);  \\ output :a : 0 , b : 3
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: If you are using C, `a ,b = 1 ? 4 , 3 : 6 , 5;` is equivalent to `b = 1 ? 3 : 5;`. That is, everything except the last argument of each comma operator is ignored. Probably not what you are hoping to do.